# Can we set a schedule for availability of an Azure SQL database?

Tags: azure-sql-database

Brand new to Azure, so please bear with me if this is obvious.

I've set up an SQL database for testing purposes. As the service is charged per hour, and it's currently only going to be used by me during my working hours, I would like to know if it's possible to have it running only during those hours.

I realise that the cost difference this will make isn't large, but I might as well not spend the money when I know it's not needed, and I'll want to know how it's done for when we start adding more services.

Comment: Check out the Serverless compute tier: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/serverless-tier-overview#:~:text=Serverless%20is%20a%20compute%20tier%20for%20single%20databases,for%20the%20amount%20of%20compute%20used%20per%20second.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Thanks for the link, but it looks like this is only available for vCore databases, which are prohibitively expensive anyway. Looks like DTU ones either exist (in which case you pay for them) or don't. Not sure why they deceive you and show billing costs per hour!

Answer (score 1):

**As of now, the simple and direct answer is No.** Azure don't allow to start/stop/pause Azure SQL Database. It starts billing once you create it. As a workaround, you can export the database and then delete it and it will stop billing.

But, as @DavidBrown mentioned in the comment, the serverless compute tier is a option which you can go with.

> The serverless compute tier for single databases in Azure SQL Database
> is parameterized by a compute autoscaling range and an auto-pause
> delay. The configuration of these parameters shapes the database
> performance experience and compute cost.

**But even in serverless compute tier, you need to pay for storage even when the database is paused.**

Add on, Serverless compute tier allows you to have auto-pausing and auto-resuming based on certain conditions.

Please go through [Auto-pausing and auto-resuming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/serverless-tier-overview#auto-pausing-and-auto-resuming) to get some insights on the same.

Comment: Thanks for the info and link, but it looks like this is only available for vCore databases, which are prohibitively expensive anyway. Looks like DTU ones either exist (in which case you pay for them) or don't. Not sure why they deceive you and show billing costs per hour!